# Is there any theory in physics that does violate momentum conservation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mathematical-physics

Momentum conservation is a most fundamental theorem in physics. Can this law be disproven? In which situations is total momentum not conserved?

Comment: You asked this very question six years ago here (see duplicate). Why did you ask it again without linking to the previous version or explaining what was not satisfactory about the answers there?

Answer (score 4):

According to Noether’s theorem momentum is not conserved whenever the Lagrangian depends on position. In other words, if the laws of physics here are not the same as the laws of physics there.

So far we have not seen any such spatial variation in the laws of physics. So although it could be disproven in principle, it has not yet been disproven.

Answer (score 3):

Momentum conservation is a law that all mainstream theories of physics have to include in their axioms in the theoretical formulation. So the answer is "no"

Conservation laws  are distillate of observations and measurements and are used as extra axioms in the mathematics used for modelling physics data and observations in order to pick up the solutions that fit and predict data.

Comment: Can a physical theory that uses inhomogenity in space be introduced?

Comment: It's not really a question of "can it be done?", it's more a question of "is it a useful and/or predictive theory of nature?".

Comment: @kryomaxim  General relativity uses  inhomogenity in space time to model gravitational observations. Locally it respects the momentum energy and angular momentum conservation laws. For consistency with laws dark energy and dark mass have been postulated in the cosmological models for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Physicists believe it is an important principle that cannot be violated.

In 1930 Pauli proposed a new particle, the neutrino, rather than have a situation where conservation of momentum (also energy) was violated.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino#Pauli's_proposal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino#Pauli%27s_proposal)

The neutrino was discovered experimentally 26 years later.

So even if there seems to be an experiment in the future where conservation of momentum is violated, it is unlikely to be accepted.  But who knows, if after postulating new particles for a long time, that cannot be discovered, maybe eventually it would have to be abandoned.

But after the neutrino experience, physicist are likely to wait centuries to be convinced.